# Confusing Preemptive Output from Reap-Sow & While Loop

Tags: output, hold

I attempted to write part of my code after what I found at ( [get while loop output into a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19349/get-while-loop-output-into-a-list) ) which is the post "get while loop into a list (duplicate)", which there shows an example

```
n = 1;
While[n < 10, 
Print[RandomSample[Join[Table["a", {2}], Table["b", {2}]], 2]]; n++]
```

This is not my code, but it gives an idea of why I structured my code this way. What you'll see below is a while loop in which I used reap and sow in hopes of making a list, which is all I need. I was successful in getting the info I needed but strangely it seems before the output starts I get a vertically lined version of the actual output that follows in the list form I specified. Here's the part of my code making it happen and what happens:

```
Flatten[Drop[Reap[d = 0; While[d < (2^n), Print[Sow[Extract[Drop[First[RealDigits[Mod[f (2^d), 1] + 1]], 1], (h - (d +4))]]]; d++]], 1]]
```

Which gives me (for my not shown variable values):

4

2

6

5

9

7

1

0

Out[(some number)]=  {4, 2, 6, 5, 9, 7, 1, 0}

I've tried everything short of throwing the kitchen sink at it to just show me the list-form output I designed but it keeps preceding the output with that stupid column and as you can imagine, as I try to evaluate large data it keeps extending to hundreds of pages. Please help me shut this thing up. The desired output should just be the list at the end, {4, 2, 6, 5, 9, 7, 1, 0}. The variable values shouldn't matter since the form is the problem.

Comment: Have a look at `Table`, `Map`, `Fold`, `Nest` and friends; if your are using loops in Mathematica you are doing something wrong. Check out [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica)

Comment: It would be helpful if you just gave (a sample of) your data and what you wanted to do with it, without `f` and `h` we can't even run your Franken code.

Comment: The column of numbers before the output is due to `Print`

Comment: @Sascha From what I'm seeing, he's `Print[]`ing his expression, and then sowing the output. It's rather convoluted.

Comment: Could I do it without Print? Sorry this is my first time using Reap and Sow

Comment: @Feyre you could use any values you wish to assign for f and h, what matters to me is that Print is causing the column output I don't need and it's an issue for large numbers. Sorry this is complicated, I'm not the most skilled coder

Comment: `Print[]` literally just prints the expression to output. But I don't see why you are using `Sow` and `Reap` in the first place. What's wrong with just a `Table[]`?

Comment: @Feyre Literally you just solved my problem: I just had to use Table in place of Print. This is what happens when you code yourself into a coma until 4am! Thank you so much! You too @Sascha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the call to `Print`.

```
With[{n = 3, f = N[Pi], h = 0},
  Flatten[
    Drop[
      Reap[
        d = 0;
        While[d < (2^n),
          Sow[
            Extract[
              Drop[First[RealDigits[Mod[f (2^d), 1] + 1]], 1],
              (h - (d + 4))]]; 
          d++]], 
      1]]]
```

> `{9, 7, 3, 8, 5, 9, 9, 5}`

Comment: Damn that's some beautiful code, thank you!

Comment: @Arlen McCracken That code is very far from beautiful (infact code like this makes most people's toe nails curl). See the comment I left on your original question about alternatives to procedural loops and have a look around popular questions to see how people code in Mathematica elegantly.